# Javascript animation with CSS anchor link

Tags: javascript, animation, anchor

How would i go about making an animation of a rocket move to another image (planet) when the user clicks on that planet.

Okay, i found out i can use a delay link clicker, but i cant find a beginner tutorial to animation :(

I want the animation to run before the redirecting to the anchor page.

```
<div id="section">
<a name="space"></a>
<a href="#mercury" onclick="DoSomething()" ><img src="merc.jpg"></a>
<a href="#venus" onclick="DoSomething()"><img src="venus.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="section">
<a name="mercury"></a></div>

<div id="section">
<a name="venus"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is create a javascript function which should be called with "onclick" event on the  tags.
In the function first you can do your animation to occur after that you can redirect to the page you want by

```
window.url="abc.com";
```